# What should I learn before learning ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have worked with ASP.NET webforms and windows application with C#  but due to the change in nature of my job, I did not  work with ASP.NET at all for 2 years. Now, I want to come back to ASP.NET and MVC is already there. I am following the tutorials on www.asp.net.

Should I learn LINQ and EntityFramework to learn MVC? Are there any other fundamental things to learn before learning MVC?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/133242)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, I want to come back to ASP.NET and MVC is already there

Nevermind! Get started with MVC!

> Should I learn LINQ and EntityFramework to learn MVC?

That is not necessarily a prerequisite. Maybe you need get used to lambdas (as they are used by many methods in MVC), so learning LINQ will guide through that.

Get a good understand of AJAX and jQuery (as it's included in the MVC stack) and you're good to go!

Answer (score 3):

Do yourself a favor and learn HTTP, then you'll be good with any framework.

Comment: +1 Agreed.  Doing web development without knowing HTTP is roughly equivalent to doing web design without knowing HTML.

Comment: @rick, thank you very much for your suggestion. As I already mentioned that I had worked with asp.net web forms, I also learned basics of HTTP.